# Can we have intercept in this model: mutually non-exclusive factors

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding, intercept

Imagine we have an experiment, where each subject consumes 2 out of 3 different kinds of chocolate bars (Mars, Snickers, Bounty) and we measure blood sugar subsequently, that is, after 2 of the bars have been eaten (the order of type of first and second is neglible in this problem) . We want to use additive model to measure outcome - sugar level with bar types as a predictor. Should we have an intercept in such a model?

Comment: If you instead recorded the treatment in terms of which bar each subject did *not* consume, would you know how to answer your question?

Comment: But if we are interested in effect associated with eating specific bar type?

Comment: The point is that when you have estimates of the effects of *not* eating one type, you can (easily) calculate estimates of the effects of eating each type.

Comment: Does it answer the question if we can have an intercept in the model?

Comment: The principles it implies will answer the question.  But I find the question incomplete, because whether you *explicitly* include an intercept depends on how you code your variables.  For details, please search our site for posts about "dummy coding" of categorical explanatory variables in regressions.

Comment: Usually we use intercept for one level of predictor, which functions then as a reference level, but it seems not to be possible to directly apply here, unless we use the trick with coding for what was not eaten.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding something, can be done multiple ways. Since you are eating two different marks before measuring, here are some ways:  (I call the marks A, B, C)

1. make a three-level factor with levels `A-B`, `A-C`, `B-C`. Whether you leave out intercept or not, is for convenience of interpretation, the models are the same.
2. Make three binary variable `A`, `B`, `C`. In your model two of them will be one  and the last one 0. These three variables will be linearly dependent (their sum is a constant 2), so leave out the intercept. Might make for the most straightforward interpretation, maybe I would use this.
3. As proposed in comments by user whuber, make three binary variables, but let it represent the one left-out mark. Or, maybe his intention was one three-level factor representing the one left-out mark. This are essentially different implementations of the same idea. The three binary variables would sum to 1 (also the three dummys representing the tree-level factor), so leaving out the intercept might simplify interpretation.